# Min/Max and most frequent element of a list

Tags: f#

I have to write a program which give in output a tuple with: min and max of a not-empty list and the value that appears most often. 
In particular:

```
min_max [1;0;-1;2;0;-4] ==> (-4; 2)
min_max: int list -> (int * int)

mode [-1;2;1;2;5;-1;5;5;2] ==> 2
mode: int list -> int
```

This is the code that I wrote for max (min is almost equal) but how can I do to receive as output a tuple with the two values?

```
let rec max_list xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> failwith "xs" "Empty list"
    | [x] -> x
    | x1::x2::xs' -> max_list((max2 x1 x2)::xs');;
```

Comment: As a side note ; your `max_list` seems a bit complicated for it's purpose ; could be simpler to pass around the current max with the rest of list and updating it if the current head is greater. or without passing it around ; just return the max between the current head and the max_list of the tail

Answer (score 5):

I'll take the first suggestion from [@Mark Seemann](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529942/min-max-and-most-frequest-element-of-a-list/33530563#33530563)'s answer and run with it, in order to make it generic, working with any collection type, and handle the case of the empty collection sensibly.

```
let tryMinMax xs =
    Seq.fold (function
    | Some(mn, mx) -> fun i -> Some(min mn i, max mx i)
    | None         -> fun i -> Some(i, i) ) None xs

[1;0;-1;2;0;-4]
|> tryMinMax
// val it : (int * int) option = Some (-4, 2)
```

For the *most frequent* part of the question:

```
let mostFrequent xs =
    xs 
    |> Seq.countBy id 
    |> Seq.maxBy snd
    |> fst

[1;0;-1;2;0;-4]
|> mostFrequent
// val it : int = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let minMax xs =
    xs
    |> List.fold
        (fun (mn, mx) i -> min mn i, max mx i)
        (System.Int32.MaxValue, System.Int32.MinValue)
```

Not particularly efficient, but fun to write:

```
let mode xs =
    xs
    |> List.groupBy id
    |> List.map (fun (i, is) -> i, Seq.length is)
    |> List.maxBy snd
    |> fst
```

Comment: Why not use a maxBy immediately, without a map ? (List.maxBy(fun (_,x) -> Seq.length x))

Comment: @FoggyFinder No particular reason :)

Comment: Because I can't use any function outside of what has been explained by the professor: and this is my problem when I have to do exercises, because also in this case I immediately thought of lis.map, list.fold, seq.fold etc.

Comment: @SimoneCalliari Normally, the exercise is to go from a recursive implementation to using a fold, but you should be able to go the other way as well.

Answer (score 0):

Option without the use of standard modules:

```
open System
let tryMinMax xs = 
    let rec minMax xs mn mx = 
        match xs with | [] -> mn, mx | h::t -> minMax t (min mn h) (max mx h)
    match xs with | [] -> None | _ -> Some(minMax xs Int32.MaxValue Int32.MinValue)
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q245xd)

On the second question - show their attempts to solve.